How should players be mechanically affected by various surfaces?
In a homebrew encounter I am creating, the party is going to be entering a dungeon which is, in fact, a large hive mind of mimics. As such, the first section of the "dungeon" is to try to appear as close to a normal underground dungeon as possible, while luring the party further in to be digested by the mimics.
Part of this which has stumped me for a while: I want a room where the floor is covered with digestive juices, which to the party first appears as regular acid of some kind. I know there have been various discussions about a fire surface in particular, but I would like some more breadth of surface mechanics to choose from. I am not entirely sold on the acid idea, so would be open to any of the following:

Acid surface
Ice surface
Sticky "glue-like" surface
Any other elemental surface that could be placed on the floor and not appear suspicious to a party.
Any items other than caltrops which create a hazardous surface semi-permanently (caltrops sprang to mind as representing mimic teeth sticking out from the floor)

In addition to any general rules to a surface, I would also accept any examples in published adventures of surfaces of some kind used against the party. Please list the mechanics of such surfaces in full; Homebrew solutions aren't necessary, as I can manage that myself if no official rules exist.
Ideally I'd like for this post to be a catalogue of sorts of all d&d-5e rules on surfaces, as I have thus far been unable to find any such posts which talk about anything but fire, lava, and occasionally acid; Really the above example is more to give a reason why such rules would be desired, so can be ignored in answers if you deem it appropriate.

I'm surprised you missed difficult terrain. That's one of the most obvious effects, and I don't even play 5e.

I mean, it’s not that I forgot it per se. Difficult terrain just isn’t one of the surfaces I gave as an example, and besides Difficult terrain is more of a condition that surfaces can have, imo, since different effects cause it in different ways

I'll start off with a few that come to my mind:

The Grease spell. It creates a slippery surface, where creatures must succeed on a Dex save or fall prone.
Icy surface: A sheet of 1-inch think ice is described in Rime of Frostmaiden on page 90f, which does not have any effect from walking on it, but can be destroyed easily, causing all creatures on it to fall down talking damage, if they miss a Dex save.
Green Slime: This is desribed on p. 105 of the DMG. It typically clings to ceilings, but you could also place it on the floor as a sticky surface that deals acid damage on contact.
Ball bearings. Described on page 151 of the PHB. You can place these on the ground to again create an area where a Dex save is needed to avoid falling prone, similar to the grease spell.


This is a really good start, thank you! Although I’d love more mechanical detail about each of these, such as perhaps excerpts from the aforementioned pages?

+1 just for finding Icy Surface defined in Rime of the Frostmaiden. The rest of these come from the main source books, but that's a (relatively) deep cut.

I could also see house-ruling that Icy Surfaces imposes difficult terrain in this dungeon, since in RotF the characters are expected to be prepared for icy conditions, and here they are not. But depending on how many other floors in this dungeon will be difficult terrain, it may feel exhausting to keep tacking that on to every room. YMMV.

I've accepted this answer for now in lieu of having a more exhaustive list, since it's genuinely been very useful in my room design. The green slime especially is a good inclusion :)
